# Laravel 4 - can't access images in public folder

Tags: laravel

I have a strange behaviour from Laravel. I just copied the website to a new hoster. Everything is working quite fine but one thing: I can't access the images in my public folder. If I try to open an image on my own with "domain.com/img/Ausfahrten/42.png i get the following error:
[error image loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb5R8.png)

The folder structure on my server looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woGBo.png)

What method can't laravel find and how can I resolve this? I've already checked file permissions on the server, everything's fine there.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why is there a public directory within your public directory? What does that folder contain?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel throw that error when it cannot find the file. Try to access to another directory without Uppercase letter in its path name.